# How does Sharepoint, specifically older versions such as 2007, store documents and their versions?

Tags: 2007

I trying to export documents from a sharepoint 2007 website. I am looking at powershell and also at the exorer virw as options. The explorer view is not working with IE.  How does Sharepoint, specifically older versions such as 2007, store documents and their versions on disk. Is the name related to the name of the doc?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint stores all the documents etc. in a Content Database, and there is not a supported way to extract the documents directly from the database.

PowerShell is not directly supported in SP 2007, but this might get you started in that direction.  [SP2007Powershell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/05/how-to-use-powershell-with-sharepoint-2007.html)

More information would be helpful as well, are you trying to archive this data to a file share, or are you migrating to a newer version of SharePoint?